# Is there any way to see which Pokestops I have already spun?

Tags: pokemon-go

Me, being a hardcore perfectionist, would like to spin as many Pokestops as possible. How am I supposed to know what stops I haven't gone to before? Is there some kind of journal that I am unfamiliar with? Keep in mind that I already know that whenever you spin a certain place, the Pokestop turns from blue to purple/pink.

Comment: But after about 5 minutes, that PokeStop turns back to blue so you can visit it again.

Comment: Also the journal in the game does tell you that you received "x items" from a PokeStop, but not sure if it tells you which stop it was. I don't have the game in front of me to verify right now.

Comment: The journal doesn't disclose that info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the answers below, as they note a feature that I was not aware of previously, and they are better responses than mine :)

My (incorrect/outdated/whatever) answer, left for reference.

> There is a history log of everything you have done so far in terms of
> pokemon encounters, gym fights and Pokestops.
>
> Select your trainer image in the bottom left of the main screen, then
> click on the "Journal" button just below your XP bar.
>
> While this does not tell you the location of the pokestop, it does
> tell you when you went there and what you received.
>
> Considering Niantic's previous game (Ingress), and how it tracked
> "unique portals" (their equivalent of pokestops/gyms), I would imagine
> the data is stored somewhere in their servers, but it is not made
> public. However, it could become public at some point in the future,
> and I would probably expect it to be connected to the journal (or just
> become a new feature).

Answer (score 12):

There will be a white circle around the top of any previously unvisited stops!

Comment: Hah, funny this wasn't been added. This is indeed the correct answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Pokestops that you have not visited yet will have a white circle around them. That circle goes away after you spin them once.

Unvisited

[image: Not visited]

Visited

[image: Visited]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The game, as of version 0.29.0, offers no public way of seeing where you have gone before. If you would like to track this information, consider using a map, and just mark off the places you've visited.

Additionally, it gives players no incentive to actually visit unique Pokestops as they (as of now) do not count towards any badges or drop any rewards.